# BUG : Unanswered questions?

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, votes

Hello Today I was browsing through all the questions... 
I was seeing and almost all the questions were answered. So I selected the "unanswered category" of questions.

By default, sort by votes (in unanswered questions:- It will show all unanswered questions and sort them by votes, so it would be something like 20votes answer in front and -4votes answer in end) is selected (at least in my case). It is OK there I don't see any answered questions and it is working fine... However, when I went to page 2, it switched to category "all" with the filter "votes". (I mean, now I no longer see any unanswered question but see all lines of questions and they are sorted by votes for eg:- It is showing an answered question with +700votes)

Is this only for me? (I am on a Samsung Tablet)

*This issue is only on mobile version*

[image]

Comment: Apparently embedded gif animations don't work here, at least not in any of my browsers.

Comment: @Paul They do work. But you need to use the URL to the gif file directly. In this case, it would be `https://i.imgur.com/JQ6Hne1.gif`. This GIF, though, is huge. I wouldn't embed it without resizing it first.

Comment: @Dan You're right. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, the mobile view [will be deprecated soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609). So, the bug will not be fixed.